# Python pptx insert an image in a table cell

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

I need to find a way to insert images into a cell of a a table in a power point presentation. I figured the only way is to set my table cell fill type to a picture. For example:

```
from pptx import Presentation

ppt = Presentation('TestPresentation.pptx')
image = 'images/myimage.png'

for slide in ppt.slides:
    for shape in slide.shapes:
        if shape.has_table == True:
            table = shape.table
            cell = table.cell(0,0)
            cell.fill.picture() = image
            print(cell.fill.type)

ppt.save('UpdatedPowerpoint.pptx')
```

With this code I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Not Important/main.py", line 14, in <module>
    cell.fill.picture()
AttributeError: 'FillFormat' object has no attribute 'picture'
```

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Use `UserPicture`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.fillformat.userpicture

Comment: I tried that a while ago. I get a "AttributeError: 'FillFormat' object has no attribute 'UserPicture' " error

Comment: Another solution to my problem could be getting the position of each individual cell and then position an image right on top of the cell, as to not attach the image to the table but to align it above the table, so if anyone knows how to do that, it would also be a great help.